# echo curl stdout into crontab

Tags: cron, pipe, curl, echo, stdout

This is my crontab pattern I store in my Github account:

```
source ~/.profile
0 0 * * *
# More cron commands
```

As an exercise I tried to pipe the stdout data of `curl` into my crontab (I've changed Github path to general pattern).

**1)** I tried using a simple pipe:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/cronjobs | crontab
```

This failed with the error:

> "-":0: bad minute
>
> errors in crontab file, can't install.

**2)** I tried using a heredoc:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/cronjobs | cat > crontab
```

This failed with the error:

> No modification made

**3)** I tried echoing the `curl` output into `crontab`.

```
echo "curl $(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/cronjobs)" | crontab
```

This failed with the error:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0...: command not found
100   505  100   505    0     0    804      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   804
(23) Failed writing body
```

---

You can see I've tried three different ways to send the data from stdout to crontab and yet nothing works. What else do I have left if I want to pass it directly to crontab and not to `cron.d` files?

Comment: So... since you've redacted the URL, it's hard to be sure—but are you confident there isn't a syntax error in the file on github?

Comment: Yes, the Github crontab file includes `source ~/.profile` in the start, and then commands (`0 0 * * 0 myCommand` and so forth).

Comment: You were right @steeldriver this is the reason. I now tested without `source ~/.profile` and it worked with the first way I tried. I must use `cron.d` instead `crontab` if I want that `source ~/.profile` in place. That's frustrating, but that's the reality in the current release... :\

Comment: Please have the honor of writing answer with that finding and I'll gladly accept.

Comment: Please see @ikkachu's very thorough answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"-":0: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
```

This is the error `crontab` gives if the file/data it's given is not a proper crontab file. (I think the number there is a line number, but I can't tell why it shows zero sometimes.) The [man page `crontab(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) says:

> An active line in a crontab is either an environment setting or a
>    cron command. An environment setting is of the form:
>    `name = value`
>    where the white spaces around the equal-sign (=) are optional...
>
> The format of a cron command is similar to the V7 standard, with a
>          number of upward-compatible extensions.  Each line has five time-and-date fields followed by a username (if this is the system crontab
>          file), and followed by a command.

So, presumably, what you entered had something that wasn't either of those.

This is ok:

```
$ crontab <<EOF
SHELL=/bin/bash
* * * * * echo foo
EOF
```

This isn't:

```
$ echo "foo" |crontab
"-":1: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
```

---

2) This isn't a here-doc, just a pipe with an extra cat and a redirection to the file `crontab`. This doesn't run the command called `crontab`.

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/cronjobs | cat > crontab
```

3) This should give you an error from the shell, you probably don't have a command called `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/cronjobs`.

```
echo "curl $(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/cronjobs)" | crontab
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line,

```
source ~/.profile
```

is not a valid line to have in one's crontab:

```
$ echo "source ~/.profile" | crontab
"-":0: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
```

If you want to source your `~/.profile` as if you were running a login shell, then consider starting your shell scripts as

```
0 0 * * * bash -l /path/to/script.sh
```

instead (for `bash`, use `sh -l` for `/bin/sh`), or possibly

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
0 0 * * * source ~/.profile && bash /path/to/script.sh
```

It's unusual to want to source one's `~/.profile` in a cron job though. If you have a specific environment variable (or set of variables) that needs to be set in the script, it would be better to set them in the script to keep the script self contained.

An alternative to that is to use a separate environment file and start your script like

```
0 0 * * * BASH_ENV="$HOME/script.env" /path/to/script.sh
```